# Android Profiler and Layout Inspector don't detect device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-profiler, layout-inspector, android-studio-chipmunk

Just installed Android studio in a new Mac and updated to Chipmunk. I was able to launch my app normally in an emulator, except I wasn't able to connect to Layout Inspector or Profiler.

Connection assistant, adb and Logcat are able to detect the Emulator.

**Android Studio info:**

> Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8512546,
> built on April 28, 2022 Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840
> aarch64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. macOS 12.3.1
> GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation Memory: 2048M Cores: 10
> Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true Non-Bundled
> Plugins: org.intellij.plugins.markdown (212.5457.16)

**Mac Info:**

[image: Mac info]

**Connection Assistant:**

[image: Troubleshoot]

**Emulator:**

[image: Emulator]

**Profiler:**

[image: Profiler]

**Layout Inspector:**

[image: Layout Inspector]

Comment: I encourage you to file a bug report to Android Studio and attach `idea.log` and `logcat`